# Can a terraform module have more than 1 source

Tags: terraform

Can a terraform module have more than a single source. Just based on the fact that source is not a list, and nothing appears to be mentioned about this in the documentation, I would think that its not possible to have more than one source. However it also feels like this might be a fairly common use case.

Comment: I'm really curious why would you think that? How would Terraform know then which one to use to deploy resources?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that each `module` block can have only one source address. However, you can have multiple `module` blocks that all refer to the same source address, which declares multiple instances of the same module.